# C# Recording Device Audio to Stream then processed by Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, naudio

I'm trying to capture my computer's audio using NAudio.WasapiLoopbackCapture, then save it to a Wavstream then pipe that into a SpeechRecognitionEngine.  I can easily save my loopback audio to a wav/mp3 file.  I can easily test a simple voice recognition with SRE.  Can I simple chain them together using:

```
using (WasapiCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture())
{
    audioStream = new MemoryStream();
    //create a wavewriter to write the data to
    //using (var w = new WaveFileWriter("C:\\users\\matth\\documents\\dump.wav", capture.WaveFormat))
    using (var w = new WaveFileWriter(audioStream, capture.WaveFormat))
    using (var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
    {
        //setup an eventhandler to receive the recorded data
        capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
        {
            //save the recorded audio
            w.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        };
        engine.SpeechRecognized += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        };
        engine.SpeechRecognitionRejected += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        };

        //start recording
        capture.StartRecording();
        audioStream.Position = 0;

        var g = new DictationGrammar();
        engine.LoadGrammar(g);

        engine.SetInputToWaveStream(audioStream);
        engine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        Console.ReadKey();

        //stop recording
        capture.StopRecording();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if you ever got anywhere with this. I'm trying to use the SpeechRecognitionEngine in a video chat application and of course it's really simple to do voice recognition via the mic, but I would really like to be able to do voice recognition for the incoming audio as well.

Comment: I don't believe I ended up figuring this one out.  If i jump onto a project doing this again, I'll be sure to update!